# Is there a Eclipse plugin for Spring JDBCTemplate code generation?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

I am planing to use Spring JDBCTemplate for all my database needs. I wanted to know if there is a Eclipse plugin which will take a data base table and auto generate -

1. The domain model POJOs
2. DAO Classes

I know such a tool already exists for hibernate(http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html). Is there a similar plugin which will help me auto generate Spring JDBCTemplate classes?

Comment: `JdbcTemplate` is best used for hand-written JDBC code. If you want auto-generated CRUD operations, you really should be using Hibernate or MyBatis (http://www.mybatis.org/index.html).

Comment: +1 Interesting point. I was in the process of implement a small application with 10-12 tables so was trying to avoid the complexity of an ORM tool.

Comment: That's the sweet spot that MyBatis hits.  It's not a full-fat ORM tool, it just does your CRUD for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a lot of research around this and now i know that there is no Eclipse plugin for my purpose.

Comment: A more charitable way to put that is “there is currently an opportunity for such a plugin to be written without competition”…

Answer (score 6):

The Telosys Tools Eclipse plugin is designed for this kind of job.

You can generate your Java (POJO) classes from the database with the basic templates
and you can also create your own template (a Velocity file) to generate your DAO classes

See http://www.telosys.org/

Comment: A bundle of templates for Spring JDBC is available on GitHub
See https://github.com/telosys-tools/persistence-spring-jdbc-TT211 
Ready to use.

Answer (score 2):

The Telosys Tools its powerful, when your choice is jdbcTemplate not ORM, you write your code for CRUD Operation per Model. If your have a lot of Model you have a lot of code for do the same things that's you need Code Gen.

Answer (score 0):

[QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com) has good [support for JDBC and generates Entities for you automatically](http://blog.mysema.com/2011/01/querying-in-sql-with-querydsl.html), however: I don't know how that would go together with JdbcTemplate, as QueryDSL "wants" to use its own object query "language" (Java-based).

It also [integrates nicely with Eclipse](http://blog.mysema.com/2010/10/using-querydsl-in-eclipse.html).

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have an option of moving away from Spring JDBCTemplates. :(

Comment: QueryDSL link is dead.

Comment: @Dale these days I'd probably recommend [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/) instead anyway.